# What geometrically is geometrically irreducible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Sorry for my bad English.

Let $k$ be field, and $X$ be finite type scheme over $k$.

Now if $X_{\bar{k}}=X\times_k \bar{k}$ is irreducible,
we say $X$ is geometrically irreducible.
(as so reduced, connected, integral)

But I confuse what geometrically?　
Please tell me origin or example ,thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Geometric" typically means happening over an algebraically closed field (or something that happens once one passes to an algebraically closed field). I don't have a precise reference for the way this terminology is used - it's common though not totally standardized in algebraic geometry, and it is frequently accompanied by a statement explaining exactly what the author means. As far as history goes, this dates back at least to EGA/SGA1 and the term "geometric point", so it's been around quite a while.

Answer (score 3):

**Question:** "But I confuse what geometrically?　 Please tell me origin or example ,thanks."

**Answer:** If you are willing to consider examples over the integers it is easy to give explicit examples. Here is an elementary geometric example of an irreducible scheme that is not "geometrically irreducible" in this generalized sense. Let $A:=\mathbb{Z}, B:=A[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$ and $k:=A/(5)A \cong \mathbb{F}_5$ - the field with $5$ elements.

When tensoring $B$ with $k$ you get

$$k\otimes_A B  \cong k[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$$

and in the ring $k$ it follows $-1 \cong 4$ and $2^2 \cong 4 \cong -1$. Hence in the ring $k[x,y]$ yo get an equality

$$x^2+y^2=x^2+2xy-2xy-4y^2=(x-2y)(x+2y).$$

It follows

$$k\otimes_A B \cong k[x,y]/((x-2y)(x+2y))$$

and the scheme $Spec(k\otimes_A B)$ is not irreducible. The original scheme $Spec(B)$ is irreducible.

**Example 1:** If you replace $A:=\mathbb{R}, k:=\mathbb{C}$ you get a similar example over fields. The polynomial $f:=x^2+y^2 \in A[x,y]$ is irreducible
but when you take the base change to $k$ you get the polynomial

$$x^2+y^2=x^2+ixy -ixy-i^2y^2=(x-iy)(x+iy) \in k[x,y].$$

It follows

$$k[x,y]/(f)\cong k[x,y]/(x-iy)(x+iy)$$

and the ring $k[x,y]/(f)$ is no longer an integral domain.

**Example 2:** If $F(x,y):=x^{2m}+f(y)^{2n}$ it follows

$$B:=A[x,y]/(F(x,y))$$

is an integral domain but

$$k\otimes_A B \cong k[x,y]((x^m+if(y)^n)(x^m-if(y)^n)$$

and $k\otimes_A B$ is no longer an integral domain.

In general if $\pi: X \rightarrow S$ is a map of schemes and $i: S' \rightarrow S$ is a morphism, the above are examples of integral schemes $X$ where the base extension $X\times_S S'$ is no longer integral.