# What does "geometric" mean?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Specifically, I would like to understand the base change $X_0\times_{\operatorname{Spec}k}\operatorname{Spec}\bar{k}$. It is related to concepts like geometric point, geometric irreducibility, etc..

What's the intuition behind "geometricity"? Is there an antonym to "geometric"?

Thanks.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4139694/what-geometrically-is-geometrically-irreducible/

Comment: I don't know that there is a single antonym to "geometric," but there are at least other categories to contrast it with. One could say, for instance, that something is a number theoretic phenomenon if happens over a field/ring of number theoretic interest (a number field, a finite field, $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q_p$,...) but no longer happens upon base changing to the algebraic closure. There is probably also something to be said about "geometric" connoting "no gaps." For instance, when we draw a line in Euclidean geometry, it's a copy of $\mathbb R$, not $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @TabesBridges I think that the antonym to 'geometric' in the way that the OP is using it is 'rational'. Like 'these irreducible components exist geometrically, but not rationally.'

Answer (score 2):

"Geometric" usually refers to base change up to the algebraic closure, as in your example. In the algebraic closure, a polynomial has "as many solutions as possible" so we are seeing the "geometric" structure of the variety without the additional constraints that are present in lower fields. For example, $x^2 + y^2 = -1$ has no solutions over $\mathbb{R}$, but has solutions over the algebraic closure $\mathbb{C}$.